# Finding first meeting point of paths in directed acyclic graph

Tags: performance, language-agnostic, graph-theory

I currently have a directed, acyclic graph with a single end vertex. Vertices are represented as objects with one or more references to vertices which they can direct to. I have the ability to find all of the paths of nodes from any given start to the end node where the path is represented as a list of node objects.

Now, say for example I am examining a node which has more than one exit. I want to find the first node at which all paths from the current node meet.I could get every path to the end then iterate through the nodes of one path, then iterate through each other path until I find this node and if I don't find it then I go to the next node of path one. However, this seems horribly inefficient as I could have to check every node in every path the length of the first path number of times. Below is my solution. Is there a way to make this more efficient?

```
for each (exitNode){
    pathList.addAll(exitNode.getPathsToSink());
}
for each (node in pathList(0)){
    bool isMeetNode = true;
    int i = 1;
    while (i < pathList.size && isMeetNode){
        i++
        isMeetNode = pathList(i).contains(node)//checks each node in the path
    }
    if (isMeetNode){
        return node;
    }
}
```

Comment: *I could get every path to the end* ― that's a rather optimistic assertion. There could be exponentially many.

Comment: Yes, there could be exponentially many. However, I have already developed an algorithm which can generate these exponentially many paths. What I would like to do now is cut down on the work that goes into processing these paths.

Comment: If you already have all N paths, make a counter in each vertex and traverse all paths, incrementing corresponding counters. The first vertex that gets the score of N is tje one you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a *positive* flow to each edge of your subgraph. It's probably easiest to work with rational numbers. Start with your starting vertex being the source of flow 1. Divide evenly between out-edges. Work your way down to the sink.

Now each vertex with a flow of 1 through it lies on all paths.  You only have to find one that is closest to the source

Comment: Ah, I see! I just got too focused on each individual path to see the full picture. Thanks!